# UICollectionView Not Appearing

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad, uicollectionview

I am trying to set up `UICollectionView` **programatically** in my view controller which extends `UIViewController`. For some reason, my collection view is not showing up at all. Below is what I have.

Why is it not appearing? I am hooking it up to the delegate and data source and adding it as a subview to `self.view`. What's missing in my code?

**In my `.h` file:**

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController
{
    @private
    UICollectionView *_collectionView;
    NSMutableArray *_results; // data source array
}
@end
```

**In my `.m` file:**

```
@interface MainViewController () <UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>
@property (nonatomic, retain) UICollectionView *collectionView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *results;
@end

@implementation MainViewController

@synthesize collectionView = _collectionView;
@synthesize results = _results;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // some init stuff - nothing to do with collection view.
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)loadView
{
    self.results = [NSMutableArray array];
    UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img1.jpg"];
    UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img2.jpg"];
    [self.results addObject:image1];
    [self.results addObject:image2];

    self.collectionView.dataSource = self;
    self.collectionView.delegate = self;

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];

    UICollectionView *collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) collectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
    self.collectionView = collectionView;

    [self.view addSubview:self.collectionView];

    [self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    [self.collectionView reloadData];

}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)view numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.results count];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView: (UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[self.results objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    return cell;
}


- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UIImage *image = [self.results objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];    
    return CGSizeMake(image.size.width, image.size.height);
}

- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(50, 20, 50, 20);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got errors trying to run your code unless I changed the loadView method to viewDidLoad -- according to the docs you're not supposed to directly call loadView.  To get the data source and delegate methods to run, I moved the lines setting the delegate and data source to self below where you set self.collectionView = collectionView

```
    self.collectionView = collectionView;
    self.collectionView.dataSource = self;
    self.collectionView.delegate = self;
```

Comment: That didn't work. I ended up subclassing `UICollectionViewController` and changing the `init` method to the one that conforms to `UICollectionViewController` and it worked. I'm having issues with `cellForIndexPath` - I will post a new post for that.

Comment: I don't know why it wouldn't have worked for you -- I just made a new app, put in your code, and made the 2 changes I mentioned, and it worked fine.

Comment: That's odd. Are you able to display items as well? I am having problems with my `cellForItemInIndexPath`. It's giving me a `could not dequeue` error. Are you not using xib/storyboard at all as well?

Comment: No. The only things I did were to create a new app from the single view template and dropped your code into the default ViewController.h and .m. I changed any mentions of MainViewController to ViewController, dragged in two images, and made the 2 changes I mentioned in my answer. I got 2 images in the upper left hand corner of the screen and no error messages.

Comment: I did the same and it worked. Funny. Are you able to scroll it up and down as well? I added the same image multiple times and I can't see to scroll. There is no flag to allow/disallow scrolling for UICollectionViews.

Comment: I just updated mine to include 80 images, and it scrolled just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your `numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:` returns `0`. For a collection view with one section, you should either return `1` or just not implement this method.

Also I cannot see where you alloc/init `self.collectionView`.

Comment: I just changed section return to 0. Please see above update. I added `UICollectionView *collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) collectionViewLayout:flowLayout]; self.collectionView = collectionView;` to `loadView` and now all I get is an empty black screen. When I changed the background of the collectionView, the screen changes its color as well as I know that the collection view is showing up. It is not invoking any data source or delegate methods though so the data is never being added at all.

Comment: @Darksky: Try moving the setup from `loadView` to `viewDidLoad`. I cannot test it myself right now, but that is the usual place for setting up custom elements of a view.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up subclassing UICollectionViewController instead of `UIViewController` and changing the init method to:

`- (id)initWithCollectionViewLayout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)layout`

and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You only had to bind your CollectionView delegate, and dataSource to ViewController in the StoryBoard.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAJ6t.png)

Comment: Describe programmatically how to do this.