# UICollectionView tutorial

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview

I am just wondering is there any tutorial out their which explains creating a `UICollectionView` pragmatically and display as a small `subView` of `mainView`.

Please Note: NO interface Builder at all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want get tutorial of `UICollectionView`  then this is [Official Document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html) and also [This one](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-uicollectionview-tutorial/)

And IF you want to get custom `UICollectionView` then [This is the best site for ever.](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=UICollectionView)

All The Best :)

Comment: @ancode- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12656910/uicollectionview-not-appearing..and also check my official document and best site fom my answer :0

Comment: http://www.mobile.safilsunny.com/introduction-to-uicollectionview-in-ios-6/

Comment: what if I need both?