# Calling setCollectionViewLayout:animated does not reload UICollectionView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uicollectionview

I am using a UICollectionView with two custom layouts - which are subclassed from `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`

When my view first loads I set it to a default view using:

```
[self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:self.tableViewLayout];
```

This calls: `cellForItemAtIndexPath` - so no problem there. This is in `viewWillAppear` method.

Then I use a UIButton to change the layout from current view to the next layout like so:

```
-(void)changeViewLayoutButtonPressed
{
    self.changeLayout = !self.changeLayout;


    if (self.changeLayout){

        [self.tradeFeedCollectionView setCollectionViewLayout:self.grideLayout animated:YES];

    }

    else {


        [self.tradeFeedCollectionView setCollectionViewLayout:self.tableViewLayout animated:YES];

    }
}
```

After this call - `numberOfItemsInSection` is called. I have checked in the debugger that the return account is not zero.

After that call, nothing else is called and my UICollectionView changes the layout but since `cellForItemAtIndexPath` is not called - the cells are not setup correctly.

if I put `[self.collectionView roloadData]` inside of `numberOfItemsInSection` - then `cellForItemAtIndexPath` is called and cells are setup.

I shouldn't need to do a manual call to reload the data in `numberOfItemsInSection`. Can someone tell me whats going on?

**Edit**

I forgot to mention I am using two different UINibs for the two different cells as they need slightly different layouts applied to them. Would this be an issue?
Thanks!

**Edit 2**

Right, so I have gotten it to work almost like I want it to. Here is all the code used for the collection view and how I change its layouts.

**The Custom Layouts**

These are subclassed from `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` - The reason I subclassed is simply due to the face my `UICollectionView` needs to look and behave very close to Apple's pre-made layout. Just different cell sizes, though.

**TableViewLayout** 
- No code in the header file. 
 **- BBTradeFeedTableViewLayout.m**

```
@implementation BBTradeFeedTableViewLayout

-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self){

        self.itemSize = CGSizeMake(320, 80);
        self.minimumLineSpacing = 0.1f;
    }

    return self;
}
@end
```

**Gride Layout** 
- No code in the header file. 
 **- BBTradeFeedGridViewLayout.m**

```
   @implementation BBTradeFeedGridViewLayout

-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self){

        self.itemSize = CGSizeMake(159, 200);
        self.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0.1f;
        self.minimumLineSpacing = 0.1f;
    }
    return self; 
}
@end
```

Then in the `ViewController` that has my `UICollectionView` - I declare the two custom layouts like so:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) BBTradeFeedTableViewLayout *tableViewLayout;
@property (strong, nonatomic) BBTradeFeedGridViewLayout *grideLayout;
```

I then register the two .xib files for the collectionView:

```
  [self.tradeFeedCollectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"BBItemTableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"TableItemCell"];
        [self.tradeFeedCollectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"BBItemGridViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"GridItemCell"];
```

Then, I have a UIButton that changes the layout:

```
    -(void)changeViewLayoutButtonPressed
{

    if (!self.gridLayoutActive){

        self.gridLayoutActive = YES;
        [self.tradeFeedCollectionView setCollectionViewLayout:self.grideLayout animated:YES];
        self.lastLayoutUsed = @"GridLayout";

    }

    else {

        self.gridLayoutActive = NO;

        [self.tradeFeedCollectionView setCollectionViewLayout:self.tableViewLayout animated:YES];
        self.lastLayoutUsed = @"TableLayOut";
    }
    [self.tradeFeedCollectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:[self.tradeFeedCollectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems]];

}
```

Finally - when a web service call is done - it calls `[self.tradeFeedCollectionView reloadData];`

So there my `UICollectionView` gets reloaded and the last method:

```
 -(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{   static NSString *tableCellIdentifier = @"TableItemCell";
    static NSString *gridCellIdentifier = @"GridItemCell";

    if (indexPath.item < [self.tradeSearchArray count]){

    if (self.gridLayoutActive == NO){

        BBItemTableViewCell *tableItemCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:tableCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([self.tradeSearchArray count] > 0){

        self.toolBarButtomItem.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d Results", self.searchResult.searchResults];

        tableItemCell.gridView = NO;
        tableItemCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        tableItemCell.item = self.tradeSearchArray[indexPath.row];

    }
        return tableItemCell;
}else

    {

        BBItemTableViewCell *gridItemCell= [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:gridCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([self.tradeSearchArray count] > 0){

        self.toolBarButtomItem.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d Results", self.searchResult.searchResults];


        gridItemCell.gridView = YES;
        gridItemCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        gridItemCell.item = self.tradeSearchArray[indexPath.row];

    }

    return gridItemCell;
    }
```

**The problem with the above code**

The above code does work. However, the cells don't animate nicely and it looks odd, almost as if a refreshed happened. Which is due to calling:

`[self.tradeFeedCollectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:[self.tradeFeedCollectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems]];`

But that is the only way I could get it to be close to what I want.

Comment: I find this question very long.

Comment: @JakubTruhlář Whats wrong with that?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`-setCollectionViewLayout:` or `-setCollectionViewLayout:animated:` won't cause your `UICollectionView` reload its data.

- If you want to change your cell style or update the data, call `[self.collectionView reloadData]` and `UICollectionViewDataSource` protocol methods will be called.
- If you want to change your `UICollectionView` layout to another, call `-setCollectionViewLayout:`. Or if you want to update your `UICollectionView` layout, just call `[self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout]`.

Cell layout and data are two different things in `UICollectionView`.

**Update**
you should discard all the stale data, probably by `-reloadData`. And calculate the new frames for every cell in your UICollectionViewLayout subclasses. Override `- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` and `- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect`.
You decide the new `contentOffset`. For instance, you could keep the indexPath of some visible cell and decide to scroll to that `indexPath` or `setContentOffset:` to the `frame.origin` of the new cell at the same `indexPath` after your layout changed.

- And I find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15523336/2638425) may give you help.
- Also check the awesome video [WWDC 2012 Advanced Collection Views and Building Custom Layouts](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/)

Comment: I want to change the cell layout from my tableView type - to grid layout. However, unless I manually ask the uicollectionview to reload - the cells are left in their old state. The only workaround I found was using this method:  [self.tradeFeedCollectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:[self.tradeFeedCollectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems]];
- however I then loose the animation and it looks odd. I would love to solve this issue. I'll even increase the bounty. :D

Comment: I'll update the question with the code I have currently

Comment: I have updated my question. As I said earlier - this code works. However the cells don't animate correctly. If I remove the workaround - they animate, however I am left with out cell data and it looks messed up.

Comment: Reload cell will cause the previous cell instance be discarded. Have you tried reloading cells data before change layout in your `-(void)changeViewLayoutButtonPressed`?

Comment: Yes. If I call: [self.tradeFeedCollectionView reloadData}; before I change the layout - it animates properly only if I am at the top of the UICollectionView. If I have scrolled down a little and change the layout, the UICollectionView disappears for half a second and resets the view to the top of UICollectionView. 

If I call:  [self.tradeFeedCollectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:[self.tradeFeedCollectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems]];

before I change layout - the cells go completely messed up until I start scrolling, then they appear normal.

Comment: Also to add: The effect I am looking for is what ebay have in their iOS app. They change between a table-like cell to a grid cell with a very nice smooth animation that keeps you at your current position. –

Comment: You could try reloadData first, and then change your layout after 0.2s. The code goes like:  [self.tradeFeedCollectionView reloadData];  dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.2 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ if (!self.gridLayoutActive){ ...} });

Comment: Nice idea. However this gives me the same issue as using self.tradeFeedCollectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:[self.tradeFeedCollectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems]] before changing the layout. Then as soon as I start scrolling cells start appearing as normal. Such odd behaviour! I also increased the time from 0.2 to 1 second. Makes no difference.

Comment: That's sure. `[self.tradeFeedCollectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:[self.tradeFeedCollectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems]]` only update the data of currently visible items. The old, incorrectly configured cells come in When you scroll, but your layout is changed at this point.

Comment: If I start scrolling, then cells show up correctly. Its before I start scrolling that the issue is present. Also, the animation is  screwed up. This shouldn't be so difficult. :-(. Appreciate your help though!

Comment: I'm confused. You mean cells display well when you use `-reloadData` but things are going different when using `-reloadItemsAtIndexPaths`?

Comment: When I use -reload data without the dispatch code you provided - cells display fine. They animate only if I am at the top of UICollectionView. If I have scrolled a little - no animation - UICollectionView shows the correct cells still - but at index.row 0 - not and index.row //where I scrolled to. If I use reloadItemsAtIntexPath - again, without the dispatch method - I get no animation - but the cells appear correctly and I am kepted at the same place I scrolled to. If I call reloadAtIndexPath BEFORE I change the layout - then I get unexpected behaviour.

Comment: When the cells are in a mess and I start scrolling, they start appearing correctly when new cells come on screen and old cells that went off screen come back displayed correctly. If I use your dispatch method - It is the same behaviour as using reloadItemsAtIndexPath before changing the layout.

Comment: I still not believe in `[self.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:[self.collectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems]]`. Your layouts are different, the itemSizes are vary. And the currently visible items may be off screen and the invisible items may be come in, due to your layout strategies. It's fine that `-reloadData` will reset the `contentOffset`. I think it's a layout issue and it's your `UICollectionViewLayout`'s responsibility to figure out how to deal with the `contentOffset`. After all, the previous offset is meaningless when your data updated and cell sizes are change.

Comment: I think you're on to something there. How would I account for the contentOffSet? This is the first time I am using UICollectionView and a custom layout.

Comment: IMHO, you should discard all the stale data, probably by `-reloadData`. And calculate the new frames for every cell in your `UICollectionViewLayout` subclasses. Override `- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` and `- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect`. You decide the new `contentOffset`. For instance, you could keep the indexPath of some visible cell and decide to scroll to that indexPath or `setContentOffset` to the `frame.orgin` of the new cell at the same indexPath after your layout changed.

Comment: I think you're right. I'll have to manage that myself. Although I have never used those methods and not sure how I would even go about implementing them. I'll see if I can't find examples online and how others have done it. You've given me the most help and I really appreciate it. Update your answer with the last comment if you like and I'll mark it as the answer. Hopefully I'll come right with those methods. Thank you again dude.

Answer (score 19):

Simply call `reloadData` **before** you switch your layout (the `performBatchUpdates` call is not mandatory):

```
[self.collectionView reloadData];
[self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
[self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:yourLayout animated:YES];
```

In Swift:

```
self.collectionView?.reloadData()
self.collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
self.collectionView?.setCollectionViewLayout(yourLayout, animated: true)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Your code, whilst it works, generates layout issues warnings in my console. The original code I posted as the solution still works. Besides the warnings, using your code, the end result is exactly the same. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Weird... I can't see any warning on iOS 8 or 9. I was facing some warnings while using `performBatchUpdates` (*trying to load collection view layout data when layout is locked*) and so I found that just putting `reloadData()` before the layout switch did the trick (without this weird warning). In any case thanks for your thread, it saves me a lot of time :)

Comment: I had to put `reloadData` before `performBatchUpdates` and the `setCollectionViewLayout` in the `performBatchUpdates` completion block.

Answer (score 1):

You should call `[self.tradeFeedCollectionView invalidateLayout];` before

```
if (self.changeLayout){
    [self.tradeFeedCollectionView setCollectionViewLayout:self.grideLayout animated:YES];
}
else {
    [self.tradeFeedCollectionView setCollectionViewLayout:self.tableViewLayout animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Thanks but self.tradeFeedCollectionView doesn't respond to invalidateLayout.

Comment: Maybe self.tradeFeedCollectionView is not your UICollectionView. Try   then: [self.collectionView invalidateLayout]

Comment: tradeFeedCollectionView is an instance of UICollectionView. declared like so: @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *tradeFeedCollectionView;

Edit: I noticed the view changes and the cells are setup incorrectly. Until i start scrolling - then they are setup incorrectly. I wonder why this is?

Comment: tradeFoodViewController does respond to invalidateIntrinsicContentSize - however it does;t reload the cells correctly. Unless I start scrolling.

Comment: Edited the quested with info I forgot to add

Comment: Also to add: The effect I am looking for is what ebay have in their iOS app. They change between a table-like cell to a grid cell with a very nice smooth animation that keeps you at your current position.

Answer (score 1):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the question author)*.

I finally found a nice and simple solution.

The marked answer was correct, that I needed to call, `-reloadData` on my `UICollectionView` - However, this destroyed the animation when switching between the two cells.

After taking in suggestions from the marked answer - I just reworked my `UIButton' method, that changes the cells

I found that if I call:

```
[self.collectionview performBatchUpdates:^{  } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

}];
```

According to the WDDC video - this animates the changes works with `-reloadData` method:

Example:

```
[self.collectionView reloadData]; 
    [self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
        [self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
        [self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:self.grideLayout animated:YES];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should only have to call this method:

```
[self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:layout animated:YES];
```

I had a similar bug, but it ended up that my subviews of the cells were not setup with Auto Layout. The cell was resizing correctly, but my subviews were not, so it looked like the cell size never changed. Check this in your code quickly by setting clipsToBounds = YES on your cell.contentView.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple trick if you want to update layouts Use it wherever you are updating the collectionView:

```
[self.collectionView removeFromSuperview]; //First remove the Collection View

//Relocate the view with layouts
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10;
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 10;

 self.collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width,100) collectionViewLayout:layout];
[self.collectionView setDataSource:self];
[self.collectionView setDelegate:self];
[self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];
[self.collectionView reloadData];

[self.view addSubview:self.collectionView];
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that to easily and nicely animate both cells' kind and layout simultaneously it is best to `reloadSections` (instead of `reloadData`) followed by setting a new layout with animation:

```
[self.collectionView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0]];
[self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:newLayout animated:animated];
```